# How can you sync multiple exchange email accounts with a windows mobile device?

Tags: exchange, windows-mobile

I use two exchange servers. Both servers allow ActiveSync and they both have IMAP and POP disabled. I want to sync like the following data

- Server 1

  - Email
  - Contacts
  - Calendar
- Server 2

  - Email

I also do not want email from Server 1 to show in the same account with email from Server 2, I'd like both email accounts to show up as separate inboxes (as if I configured multiple IMAP/POP accounts). I do not want any cross pollination of data between the two servers, Server 2 should not have Contacts/Calendar synchronized so data from Server 1 should never be synced to Server 2 and visa-versa.

How can I configure my Windows Mobile 6.1 device to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to setup more than one profile to sync with more than one exchange server on a device. the only way to do it is to use IMAP or POP to sync with other exchange servers (if they provide an IMAP or POP front). obviously you have that disabled so it wont work